# How to minimize data returned from SharePoint 2013 REST search api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest

In sp2013 rest, you can get json returned. But also depending on the header type, you can specify a no metadata option to get less data as shown here.

http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/06/improving-rest-api-performance-in.html?m=1

However in all the examples I've seen, this is for a non-search rest call. Combined with this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx

Does anyone know what combination of url paramaters with their values to use to minimize the data being returned from a search rest query? I am only interested in the result set and no other data.

Thanks